# Restrict hadoop client to not to create hidden checksum files

Tags: hadoop, client, hdfs

CopyToLocal command is creating a hidden checksum file. Is there a way to avoid this being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're running a very old version, Apache Hadoop only creates the local checksum file if you opt in to creating it by passing the `-crc` option as showing in the Apache Hadoop documentation for the [copyToLocal](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyToLocal) command.

```
> hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /LICENSE.txt

> ls -lrta
drwxr-xr-x+ 131 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   4.3K Jan 27 09:18 ../
-rw-r--r--    1 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   140K Jan 27 10:11 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x    7 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   238B Jan 27 10:11 ./

> hdfs dfs -copyToLocal -crc /LICENSE.txt

> ls -lrta
drwxr-xr-x+ 131 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   4.3K Jan 27 09:18 ../
-rw-r--r--    1 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   140K Jan 27 10:07 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   1.1K Jan 27 10:07 .LICENSE.txt.crc
drwxr-xr-x    8 naurc001  SWNA\Domain Users   272B Jan 27 10:07 ./
```

If you have the option, then I recommend running a current version and testing to make sure the `-crc` option is not being passed anywhere.

Comment: Yes i agree there is an option for CopyToLocal. There is no such option for getmerge command and by default crc file will be created. Anyway to avoid in this case?

Comment: @Nick , that's a great find!  You are correct that `-getmerge` has no such option.  I encourage you to file an Apache JIRA issue to request the feature, and if you feel like it, consider contributing a patch.  Thank you!